# recursively getting sum of a nested list

Tags: python, recursion

```
def rsum(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        result = L[0]
    elif type(L[0]) == type([]):
        if len(L[0]) == 0:
            result = []
        else:
            current = [L[0][0]]
            rest = L[0][1:]
            result = rsum(current) + rsum(rest) + rsum(L[1:])
    else:
        result = L[0] + rsum(L[1:])
    return result


print(rsum([1,2,[3,4],5]))
```

This is my attempt. This would work if the list is very simple like this:

```
print(rsum([1,2,[3,4],5])) -> 15
```

But complicated ones like this: [[1], [2, [3]], []] fail

I'm just wondering if this is possible to do by doing minus 1 strategy? I've been stumped on this for a while.

Loop are not allowed

Comment: Your brackets are not balanced, and the code is syntactically incorrect. Please paste the _actual_ code.

Comment: so, this is a homework assignment?

Comment: Sorry I missed a bracket fixed now. And its an exercise question so yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def rsum(L):
    if type(L) != list:
        return L
    if L == []:
        return 0
    return rsum(L[0]) + rsum(L[1:])
```

Comment: Simple and Good one !